# PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::prophesize() is deprecated and will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Please use the trait provided by phpspec/prophecy-phpunit

Tags: phpunit, magento2.4.5p1

While running php unit test, I got the following error.

please help

Vendor\yyy\Test\Unit\Service\ImporterTest::test_validatePath with data set #1 (true, false) PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::prophesize() is deprecated and will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Please use the trait provided by phpspec/prophecy-phpunit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are using the prophesize() method in PHPUnit, which has been deprecated and will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Instead, you should use the ProphecyTrait provided by the phpspec/prophecy-phpunit package.

To fix the issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Install the phpspec/prophecy-phpunit package using Composer:

   ```
   composer require --dev phpspec/prophecy-phpunit
   ```
2. Add the ProphecyTrait to your test case class:

   ```
   use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
   use Prophecy\PhpUnit\ProphecyTrait;

   class MyTest extends TestCase
   {
       use ProphecyTrait;

       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Replace the prophesize() method calls with the $this->prophesize() method calls:

   ```
   $myObject = $this->prophesize(MyClass::class)->reveal();
   ```
4. Run your PHPUnit tests again.

This should resolve the error and allow you to run your tests successfully.